# ExtJS dynamic tabIndex ordering after render

Tags: extjs, extjs4, field, lifecycle, tabindex

I'm trying to assign new tabIndexes after dom elements are given X and Y coordinates.
Basically, I am able to retrieve X and Y in afterLayout event of the form.
When I try to assign new tabIndex within afterLayout, it does not get applied to the fields.

Is there a stage in page lifecycle where I am able to apply new tabIndex whilst having XY coordinates?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could actually add `afterrender` listener and bind it to your component:

```
listeners: {
            afterrender: function(component, eOpts) {
                //component = current component that has been rendered
                //your code here
            }
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything ? Any progress ?